# go get remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it

Tags: go, gitlab, goland

I am using go 1.20.1 , Windows 10 x64, GoLand 2022.3.2 .

Go to `...` , create file `.netrc` with content

```
machine gitlab.com login my_username password my_password
```

Set environment variable

[image]

then get dependency

```
go get gitlab.com/foo/bar/baa/fuu
```

Error

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html), not your actual GitLab account password, in `%USERPROFILE%\_netrc`.

Second use `go get gitlab.com/foo/bar`, not `foo/bar/baa/fu`.
As in `go get gitlab.com/name_or_group/repo_name`.

Answer (score 1):

on Windows OS, it is not `.netrc` , it is `_netrc` (underscore character) , and not use password, use GitLab access token.